# How to get the address of a global variable in Fortran at initialization?

Tags: binding, fortran

In C, I can initialize a pointer type global variable in this way:

```
<<file.h>>
extern int dummy;
extern int* p;

<<file.c>>
int dummy;
int* p = &dummy;
```

The advantage is that p is a const at link time. I do not need to write an init function to initialize p. Since in my case, value of 'dummy' is never used, I only need its address p and I won't change p.

I want to know how to achieve this in Fortran, i.e., getting the address of a variable without execution time initialization. I did the following, but did not succeed.

```
module mod
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_loc
  integer, target :: dummy
  type(c_ptr), bind(c, name="p") :: p = c_loc(dummy) 
end module mod
```

The compiler says "Error: Intrinsic function 'c_loc' at (1) is not permitted in an initialization expression"

I need this feature since I have a variable declared in Fortran. I need its address in C (to be used as a global var), but I don't want to call any Fortran init routines.

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: Use an executable statement at run time.

Comment: For a short time, there was actually a proposal to allow c_loc in constant expressions (what used to be called initialization expressions), but fortunately, sanity prevailed. I don't understand why you need this, though. You can have a bind(c) variable that is the same as "dummy" and can get its address at run-time.